# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. (While uploading app on google play store for the first time)

Tags: react-native, google-play-console, sha, android-app-bundle

I am uploading my first release on google play store everything is working fine (app is working fine also build is successful) , I tried rebuilding the app many time with following the docs on react native official website but while uploading it is giving me above error with SHA key

I tried many solution on stackoverflow but nothing works for me as most of the solution is for second time release but mine is first time

Please help me I wasted my 6 hours on this but I am not getting solution

Comment: Are you sure you used the same release keystore that you've used before (when uploading the build to google play) to sign the build?

Comment: this is first time i am uploading build to google play @dianaqqq

Comment: Oh, I got it now. I thought you did another build afterwards. And did you generate correctly the release keystore?

Comment: yes nearly 10 times i did it again and again app is running smooth no build error @dianaqqq

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer
Steps:

1. Open the project in android studio and clear the project .
2. Then rebuild it after gradle sync .
3. Then Generate the keystore (in android studio).
4. Then Generate Apk (in android studio).
5. Setup everything again on google play console .
6. Then try uploading .aab file again on google play console

Comment: Nice, Just remove the app in google play and create a new app in google play and it will work